# ReactJS Javascript - Is there any way to assign this.state to a variable / constant and 'freezing' the value for the variable / constant from then?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently working on an Update Form in ReactJS and came across some issue. Basically, I am mapping a bunch of data to be rendered as input fields (since it is an update field, the data contains the value of the input field). However, whenever a new row of field is added, it is added to that same this.state data to be ultimately sent back as form data in a PUT request. Hence, whenever a new row is added, effectively, two rows would be added since the mapping of the this.state would continue. Hence, is there any way for me to assign the this.state data at the start to a constant / variable, and make it such that the data assigned to that variable / constant is frozen then and there, and even if this.state changes, it does not affect said variable / constant? Thanks for the help and look forward to the replies!

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show some code of where you're currently at.

Comment: Do you mean that you need a constant variable stored in state which cannot be updated?

Comment: Some code would be helpful. I can take a shot without fully understanding what you're trying to achieve, though:

Perhaps you could store the fetched data in one part of the state, and new fields in another part of the state. Only update the server with the new entries.

You don't have to send the full state object back to the server.

Comment: sorry for not pasting the code here, i was not sure what would be useful to show here. but i solve the issue with the help of Burak below already, thank you so much for your comments though :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign initial data set to your component like that;

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);

  // Let assume props.formData is something like that.
  // props.formData = {
  //   id: 0,
  //   name: "burak"
  // };

  this.state = {
    formDataSet: props.formData
  };

  this.initialFormDataSet = props.formData;
}
```

And now you can access `this.initialFormDataSet` anywhere inside your component.